# Updating a counter in Rails, does this have concurrency issues?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I allow people to vote on items, and I am doing this:

```
bid = Bid.new
..
bid.save!


item.total_bids += 1
item.save!
```

Won't this have issues if multiple people are biding on an item at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely it can have concurrency issues.  Rails provides increment_counter to handle this:

```
Item.increment_counter( :total_bids, item.id )
```

This runs the SQL on the database:

```
UPDATE items SET total_bids = total_bids + 1 WHERE id = x
```

See here for more details:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache.html#method-i-increment_counter

Comment: What if I want to set the count to 10, or decrement by 2?

Comment: Then see the more generic update_counters routine: Item.update_counters item.id, :total_bids => -2

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Sidekiq` or a have a `.delay` method with some similar job queue try this:

```
Item.delay.increment_counter(:total_bids, item.id)
```